# Center progress bar in the middle of the page?

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This works but it moves the whole page down to the middle and replace it with black background. I mean it shows in the middle of the page not the content. The content gets pushed down.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJKYe.jpg)

Comment: I think what you want is an `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: You can use [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Comment: Remove this  `android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"` and follow @Reena 's answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RelativeLayout** places your UI elements in comparison to other elements. That's why it's getting pushed down. You either need to replace it, or modify the code.

In this case, just remove **android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"** from **WebView**. This repositions everything in center.

Now, place **WebView** above **ProgressBar** to bring and view **ProgressBar** on top of **WebView**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can also use **FrameLayout** in place of **RelativeLayout** in this code. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks buddy works. However RelativeLayout is not centering the spinner it shows on the top left side!

Answer (score 0):

Change relative layout to FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This will do you job. Also this layout processing is much faster than the RelativeLayout and it will increase your application performance (not visible to users)

Comment: updated the answer. progressbar had to be written below webview.

Answer (score 0):

This may helpful for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"     />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can hide/show progress bar as per your requirement

Comment: Awesome works great. As mentioned above FrameLayout seems to be faster. How to make this work with FrameLayout?

Comment: Simple just need to Replace '<RelativeLayout>' with '<FrameLayout>' in above code

Comment: Spinner is not centered not sure why shows on the left top corner

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps..